# How to set the data-bind=Visibility false using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I do have following code

```
 <div id="tab1" data-bind="visible: saleListVM.showSortPanel && auctionBranchListVM.SelectedItem() && saleListVM.ItemsCount() > 0">
       <ul id="tabnav">
            <li data-bind="click: saleListVM.sortTabClicked, css: { tab1: saleListVM.showSortPanel() }"><a href="index.html">@Html.LocalizeText(Resources.RT_GENERAL,"Sort")</a></li>
            <li data-bind="click: saleListVM.groupTabClicked, css: { tab1: saleListVM.showGroupsPanel() }"><a href="#">@Html.LocalizeText(Resources.RT_GENERAL,"Group")</a></li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Function

```
groupTabClicked: function (val) {
        GAForNewListingAndDetails('New AC Listing', 'Sale List GROUP Click', '');
        saleListVM.showGroupsPanel(true);
        saleListVM.showSortPanel(false);
        saleListVM.altView(false);
        loadGroupSaleList(auctionGroupListVM.selectedGroupItem());
        detailWidth();

    },
    sortTabClicked: function (val) {
        GAForNewListingAndDetails('New AC Listing', 'Sale List SORT Click', '');
        saleListVM.showGroupsPanel(false);
        saleListVM.showSortPanel(true);
        saleListGroupTypeId = null;
        saleListGroupId = null;
        saleListGroupName = "";
        saleListVM.DisplaySortByLane(true);
        saleListVM.DisplaySortByItem(true);
        initSaleListScroller();
        detailWidth();

    },
```

here In DOM element i.e.div with id=tab1 is to be hidden when groupTabClicked() is called and to be shown when sortTabClicked() is called

Comment: And when and how do you call those functions?

Comment: on First li with data-bind="click: saleListVM.sortTabClicked the sortTabClicked function is called and same way on second li data-bind="click: saleListVM.groupTabClicked the function groupTabClicked is being called

Comment: I would rather ask you post the generated HTML than the ASP(?) version as it's easier to help that way!